# AES using FIXED IV Key ..when combined with Diffie-Hellman key exchange

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, public-key, encryption-symmetric

Scenario:
1) Multiple clients connect to a WebAPI.
2) Client requests a Diffie-Hellman Exchange Key during their initial hand-shaking and then reuse the "shared secret key" for the next API call only if this occurs within 20 seconds (Shared Keys expire after 20 seconds on the server).

What's the recommended Encryption method using this "shared secret key"?
It seems to be AES but then I have the problem of the IV value.

Can the IV be a fixed value for ALL clients?
Can the IV be public just within those set of client calls blocks?
Should the IV be relevant somehow to the shared secret key?

Is there a better or similar encryption mechanism that does only need a key (no IV, no other values needed)?

Comment: The IV should be different and random for every encryption operation. It need not be secret.

Comment: Any reason you aren't just using SSL? Given that this is already a web API, it should be trivial to add, and minimal additional development is required by either you or your clients. It will likely also be more secure than any mechanism you would build yourself.

Comment: Yes the API runs under SSL already. This extra step is to encrypt licensing info sent back and forth between various clients and the server ....so I'm assuming this should be encrypted further anyway, or am I wrong on this?

Comment: Your communications are already secure against eavesdropping, man-in-the-middle attacks and tampering by virtue of being transmitted over an SSL protected channel, what threat are you trying to mitigate with additional encryption?

Comment: Well, maybe is mis-information on my side. I do have SSL but kind of felts to add extra encrypt when sending back and forth the registration and license info. 

Are we saying that SSL is enough and if I was sending the license info in plain text ...it would still remain super secure?

Comment: I think you can rest assured that SSL is more than capable of protecting your license info. Remember, crypto is very hard to get right, so given the choice it's generally much safer and more secure to go with an established, proven system (like SSL) than try to roll your own.

Comment: I suppose one could argue that SSL relies on the trust of certificate authorities and you'd like to add an extra layer that does not depend upon that trust.  But unless you are an expert in this area, you're probably going to spend a lot of effort to little benefit (as owl already pointed out, there are a lot of issues with what you are proposing).  I agree with the others: stick with SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 3):

The IV should be random for CBC mode encryption. Using AES in CBC mode is fine, you can simply prefix the IV to the ciphertext. You can use a fixed IV, or just a zero-valued IV *if and only if* you never use the key to create another ciphertext. Alternatively can also use CTR mode and a nonce. The nonce only has to be unique and may be derived from other data.

You should always add integrity and authentication if you want to create a *transport protocol*. The easiest way to do this is to add a HMAC over the IV and ciphertext. Preferably a different key should be used; you can do this by creating two keys using a *KDF* from the secret and some distinguishing data (this can be something simple like a secure hash). You *must* check the authentication tag *before* you decrypt in CBC mode (or use the plaintext for stream cipher modes).

Note that just using DH makes you vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. You must verify the DH public key *and* add some kind of authentication as well.

Because of all the pitfalls (there are more) people normally opt for some TLS ciphersuite instead.

Comment: I'll look into your options... Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I agree with owlstead's reply, but I'll try to make a simple reply:

- use AES in either Gcm or CBC mode.  CBC is most common.  Both require an IV.  No there is not a better option that doesn't use an IV.
- IV cannot be fixed.  Must be generated for each new encryption.  Suggest using a cryptographically secure random number generator for generating it.
- IV is not a secret value.

As owl mentioned, you need more than Diffie Hellman to do this securely, because you are leaving yourself open to man in middle attack the way you describe it.  Additionally, owl correctly points out other security issues that you should deal with.

I general, we all agree that your best bet is to just stick with SSL/TLS.  This stuff is very hard to get right.

Comment: Gotcha !! So my next question is: if I use Diffie-Hellman and SSL ...do I still need to encrypt (using AES) the various Registration/Licensing objects transmitted via the, or SSL is enough and so I can just pass clear objects from the client to the APIs?